# Multiply numbers in / within text strings. +Roundup

Tags: excel, vba

Overview:

A1 = Dog_dkp_1,Cat_dkp_50,Mouse_dkp_20

=Nmult(A1,3)

Multiplies the numbers in cell A1 by 3.
And you get:

Dog_dkp_3,Cat_dkp_150,Mouse_dkp_60

I could use an optional roundup parameter.

=Nmult(A1,1.1,0)

=Nmult ( target, multiplier, roundup to point )

Results in : Dog_dkp_2,Cat_dkp_55,Mouse_dkp_22

... Its not mine to begin with...

> Function Nmult(text As String, multiplier As Double)
>
> ```
> Dim i As Long, char As String, numb As String
> Application.Volatile True
> For i = 1 To Len(text)
>     char = Mid(text, i, 1)
>     If char Like "#" Then
>         While char Like "#"
>             numb = numb + char
>             i = i + 1
>             char = Mid(text, i, 1)
>         Wend
>         char = Str((CLng(numb) * multiplier)) + char
>         numb = Empty
>     End If
>     Nmult = Nmult + char
> Next i
> ```
>
> End Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple small changes are needed for what you want.  I added an option variable in the function definition and the RoundUp function in your calculation.

```
Function Nmult(text As String, multiplier As Double, Optional roundValue As Double)
    Dim i As Long, char As String, numb As String
    Application.Volatile True
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        char = Mid(text, i, 1)
        If char Like "#" Then
            While char Like "#"
                numb = numb + char
                i = i + 1
                char = Mid(text, i, 1)
            Wend

            char = Str(Application.RoundUp((CLng(numb) * multiplier), roundValue)) + char
            numb = Empty
        End If
        Nmult = Nmult + char
    Next i
End Function
```

---

Tested: (Column B shows what formulas are in adjacent Column A cells

[image]

---

*Edit*

`CLng` adds a leading space to the result.  One way to remove it is by trimming the string.  Change this line:

```
char = Str(Application.RoundUp((CLng(numb) * multiplier), roundValue)) + char
```

To this:

```
char = LTrim$(Str(Application.RoundUp((CLng(numb) * multiplier), roundValue)) + char)
```

Comment: thx for that, I'll also rename the title so more people can find it and use it. This function is pretty handy for that sort of thing.

Comment: Is there a way to update this function so that it works also for numbers with a decimal point?  In addition, the function works well also with numbers having a leading dollar sign (e.g., $45), but the output of the function returns a space between dollar sign and number (e.g. $ 45). Is it possible to remove the space?

Comment: @Egodym - `CLng` is adding a leading space that I didn't notice before.  To remove, trim the resulting string using `LTrim$()`  see edit above.